# Pass template to function as an argument in c++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I want to create a queue of structure (Category) sorted based on a parameter (action). For that, I'm using std::priority_queue (pQueue) template. When I build the code, I get the following errors:

1. `error: redefinition of ‘pQueue::pQueue()’`
   -> Used `#pragma once` to avoid multiple header file inclusions, still getting this error.
2. `error: use of deleted function ‘pQueue::pQueue(constpQueue&)’ note: ‘pQueue::pQueue(const pQueue&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:`
   -> How do I define custom constructor which can incorporate the information as shown in the code below?
3. `error: ‘q’ was not declared in this scope` (scope: queueWork in file.cpp)
   Where do I declare 'q'?

How do I resolve these errors?

The main objective is to queue the data when function() is executed multiple times and later on use that data.
The below code snippets are a part of a bigger project. Hence, might miss out on a few details.

file.cpp

```
#include "File.h"
using namespace std;

pQueue::pQueue()
{
  std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q;
}

pQueue::~pQueue()
{
}

void queueWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q, int action, Category* data)
{
  q.emplace(make_pair(action, data));
}

void doWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q, bool flag)
{
  while (true)
  {
    std::pair<int, Category*> queueElement;
    queueElement = q.top();
    Category* data = queueElement.second;
    // Perform some operation, get return value
    q.pop();
  }
}
```

file.h

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

class pQueue
{
public:
  pQueue() {
  }

  ~pQueue() {
  }

 void queueWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q, int action, Category* data);

private:
  void doWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q, bool flag);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "File.h"
bool function(Category* data)
{
    bool result;
    if (data)
    {
        // Will set action values later
        auto action = 1;
        pQueue::queueWork(Queue, action, data);

        // TODO: Implement getResult function to get the return value
        // result = pQueue.getResult()
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your errors do not match presented code. There is no `Queueing` class or its constructor, `pQueue` is copyable as far as I can tell and there is no use of `dataQueue` anywhere. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: A couple observations about the code. There's no point in setting `flag = false;` in the destructor of `pQueue`; the object is going away, and its members will no longer be accessible. In fact, that `flag` member is pointless, since it's always `true` thoughout the lifetime of the object. And in the function `doWork` the value of the argument `flag` is never changed, so either the loop never executes (`doWork` called with a `flag` value of `true`) or the loop runs forever (`doWork` called with a `flag` value of `false`).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: sorry, updated the logs

Comment: @PeteBecker: this flag is actually a conditional variable that will be used to construct and destruct thread that will execute using the data in the queue.

Comment: @JHBonarius: the code snippet added is a part of the main function. Since rest of the code was not relevant, hence not added in this post.
No, not including file.cpp

Comment: @Friday -- if those uses of `flag` have nothing to do with the question they should be removed.

Comment: _" this flag is actually a conditional variable that will be used to construct and destruct thread that will execute using the data in the queue."_ ?? what does this mean at all? a lot of words but no context. `flag` is a member of the class, so it's gone when the object is destroyed....

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thanks for the input, made edits in the post.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Thanks for the info, still have some doubts around it. Will create a separate post for the same :)

Comment: Got hung up on the details. The immediate problem is that `file.h` defines `pQueue()` and `~pQueue()`, and `file.cpp` also defines them. Pick one! Also, the constructor in `file.cpp` creates an object of type `std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>>` named `q` and immediately discards it.

Comment: @PeteBecker If I want to create a constructor wherein I want to declare some variables, how and in which file do I do that? Its not clear to me

Answer (score 1):

In your `file.h` you do not only declare the constructor, but also define it:

```cpp
class pQueue
{
public:
    pQueue() {
        flag = false;
}
```

Next, in your `file.c` file you redeclare the constructor:

```cpp
pQueue::pQueue()
{
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q;
}
```

That's not possible. C++ has the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). There must only be one definition here.

Comment: Thanks for the input, any comments on 2nd error?

Comment: @Friday SO guidelines say "one question per question" i.e. you should focus on one thing per question.
But, you seem to be in need of a good course or book on C++. Especially error 3 shows that. The second error is not reproducible with the current code. Likely cause:  you need to follow ["the rule of five"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (or better, the rule of zero).

Comment: Noted! It is actually the case, just starting with c++. Well, thanks for the reference and inputs :)